# Why isn't this working in my Genesis!! remove_action with conditional tags

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

Hi I built a navigation widget which works and looks great, showing the logged in person from Buddypress, but obviously I want it to be hidden on the main navigation, the login pages etc..

I'm pulling my hair out here because by all purposes what I'm doing is right? - But it's simply not working, would really appreciate some assistance here! Thanks

```
/** Register Utility Bar Widget Areas. */
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
 'id' => 'utility-bar-left',
 'name' => __( 'TRN Member Utility Bar left', 'theme-prefix' ),
 'description' => __( 'This is the left utility bar above the header.', 'theme-prefix' ),
) );
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
 'id' => 'utility-bar-right',
 'name' => __( 'TRN Member Utility Bar Right', 'theme-prefix' ),
 'description' => __( 'This is the right utility bar above the header.', 'theme-prefix' ),
) );


add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar' );

function utility_bar() {

 echo '<div class="utility-bar">';

 genesis_widget_area( 'utility-bar-left', array(
 'before' => '<div class="utility-bar-left">',
 'after' => '</div>',
 ) );

 genesis_widget_area( 'utility-bar-right', array(
 'before' => '<div class="utility-bar-right">',
 'after' => '</div>',
 ) );

 echo '</div></div>';
}

add_action('genesis_before_header','remove_bar');

function remove_bar() {
if (is_home() || is_page(www.trnworld.com) || is_page(trn-login) || is_front_page() ) { //Replace post_type with your post type slug
remove_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'genesis_register_sidebar' );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wordpress documentation:

> Important: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.

`add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar' );`

does not match

`remove_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar', 5 );`

Additionally You have added the action for displaying the widget and the action for removing the action that displays the widget to the same hook.

From Wordpress documentation on add_action

> $priority
>   (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>
> Default value: 10

You've added both actions with same default priority of 10 and since `add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar' );` is added before `add_action('genesis_before_header','remove_bar');` it is running first when the do_action function is called on genesis_before_header printing out the widget; after which the second function runs performing remove_action on an action which has already been performed.

See what happens if you change

`add_action('genesis_before_header','remove_bar');` to `add_action( 'genesis_before_header','remove_bar', 9 );`

and

`remove_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar', 5 );` to `remove_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'utility_bar' );`

Unrelated note in your function utility_bar() I see 2 closing divs but only one opening. I'm guessing this will cause layout problems in one of the states of being shown.